# Error in R trying to estmate a VAR model

Tags: r, time-series, var

I get this error when I try to estimate in R a VAR model with explanatory variables:

```
est<-VAR(varm, lag.max = 20, type= "const", ic = "AIC", exogen = exog)
Error in VAR(varm, lag.max = 20, type = "const", ic = "AIC", exogen = exog) : 
unused arguments (lag.max = 20, type = "const", ic = "AIC", exogen = exog)
```

What is it due to? Thank you

Comment: I strongly suspect that it is due to the fact that the `VAR` function has been called with `unused arguments`.

Comment: yeah ok but I can't understand why it says so since all the arguments should be correct

Comment: Specify the package you are using to estimate the `VAR`. For example, the `VAR` function is available in `vars` package and `MTS` package with different arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In line with @Ahmed Salhin's suggestion, closing R and not loading the MTS but only the vars library solved the problem.

You can also use:

```
detach("package:MTS", unload = TRUE)
```

if you want to use both libraries in the same code.